# My Image doesn't hover over my Div, even with "position: absolute;" & "postion: relative;"

Tags: html, css

I already tried it with "position: absolute;" & "postion: relative;" but it still doesn't work.
Thank you for your help!

html:

```
<div id="blackBar"></div>

<div class="banner_img"> <IMG SRC="img/banner.png"> </div>
```

css:

```
.banner_img img {
width: 100px;
height: auto;
       margin:0px;
   display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto


}



#blackBar{

position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:black;

   }


  html{
 height:173px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the z-index of any positioned elements. Setting the z-index of the bar to -1 will display it behind the img. You can read more about this property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)